# Polymorphic inheritance in SQLAlchemy with reflection

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have two tables, the schemas look like this:

```
Table Auth:
 id: Integer, PrimaryKey
 type: String

Table Password_auth
 id: Integer, PrimaryKey, ForeignKey(Auth.id)
 password: String
```

I am using join inheritance in SQLAlchemy to represent the above two tables in their classes. I am using type as a discriminator for polymorphism. This all works fine as long as I do not use reflection. As soon as I use reflection, all hell breaks loose.

Can one use polymorphic join inheritance with reflection in SQLAlchemy? If so, would someone care to take a crack at giving me an example on how it is done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`declarative` extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/declarative.html), the code below should give you an idea:

```
class Auth(Base):
    __table__ = Table('Auth', Base.metadata,
            autoload=True,
            autoload_with=engine)
    __mapper_args__ = {
            'polymorphic_on': 'type', 
            'polymorphic_identity': 'auth',
            }

class Password_Auth(Auth):
    __table__ = Table('Password_Auth', Base.metadata,
            autoload=True,
            autoload_with=engine)
    __mapper_args__ = {
            'polymorphic_identity': 'password_auth',
            }
```